# What is the argument passed into RSpec's double method used for?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, mocking

When creating a Test Double in RSpec, I have the option to pass in a string which seems to "name" the double. I'm finding it hard to find documentation about this argument, [the top result on google](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/test-doubles) doesn't seem to mention it.

I made a test to play around with it and as far as I can tell it just used to for presentation/printing purposes. Does it have any use outside of this?

[image: double example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sets a title for the double to be used in error messages.

```
#<Double "A Double"> received unexpected message :foo with (no args)
```

If you have multiple doubles, it will help you to figure out which one received an unexpected message.

In addition to the title, you can make your double respond in a predefined way to a method without using something like `allow(double_x).to receive(:foo).and_return('bar')` to set it up:

```
let(:double_x) { double("Double X", foo: 'bar') }
# double_x.foo 
# => "bar"
```

The title is optional and can be left out.